# Strange behavior of a script when executed from /etc/profile.d/

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I'm trying to auto-run a bunch of processes at system startup, after a user logs in. Here is the create_processes.py script that I will use to start some processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess 

def f1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "I'm alive"
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "assuming main"
    subprocess.Popen([""/usr/bin/python",sys.argv[0],"f1"])
elif sys.argv[1] =="f1":
    f1()
```

If I directly invoke it or if I try with `nohup python create_processes.py 2>&1 &` everything works fine.

The problem rises when I try to make it run invoked by a script inside the /etc/profile.d/ folder. Such script simply contains the above command. Using `ps` I can not find the children anymore. What happens in such context?

Thank you for your time and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in `/etc.profile.d/` are sourced when `/etc/profile` is executed.

Here are the relevant lines from `/etc/profile`:

```sh
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

From this lines we can see, that only files which names ends with `.sh` are going to be sourced.

If the name of your custom file doesn't end with `.sh`, rename it accordingly, otherwise it will not be sourced.